# Two disks MD RAID 1 setup running with one disk

Tags: hard-disk, raid, mdadm

I have MD RAID 1 with two disks but one failed and will be replaced soon but till this time is it possible to set the raid to active to access my files because now the state is inactive ?

Thank you.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sda[0](S)
      976630488 blocks super 1.2
       unused devices: <none>
```

```
mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=5a9ac94a:0f72fb2d:ea24d20f:e7a808f0 name=m_nas:0
```

```
mdadm --detail $(mdadm --examine --scan | awk '/ARRAY/{gsub("md/","md",$2); print $2}' | xargs )

/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 1

              Name : m_nas:0
              UUID : 5a9ac94a:0f72fb2d:ea24d20f:e7a808f0
            Events : 13368

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8        0        -        /dev/sda
```

---

### Last edits

I made the failed HDD to boot and the raid status is active again.

The output:

`cat /proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb[1] sda[0]
      976630464 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

`mdadm --examine --scan`

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=5a9ac94a:0f72fb2d:ea24d20f:e7a808f0 name=m_nas:0
```

Now I will try to set `sdb` HDD as failed in the RAID and will remove it and probably I will continue to see and access the files on the HDD.

---

### After removing the failed HDD

`cat /proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sda[0]
      976630464 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

`mdadm -D /dev/md0`

```
    /dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Jan  6 02:03:43 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 976630464 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976630464 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Oct  7 09:55:34 2020
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : m_nas:0
              UUID : 5a9ac94a:0f72fb2d:ea24d20f:e7a808f0
            Events : 13371

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       -       0        0        1      removed
```

So I was able to boot with the failed HDD and software removed it from the RAID and now I'm have access to my other HDD and the RAID is still active but my question is if my HDD ever failed and won't turn on at all is it possible to access my other HDD from the RAID to recover my info ?

Comment: This is very strange because It was configured as RAID 1 ..... At the evening will try to make the failed HDD turn on.

Comment: @fra-san I've just tested with a RAID1 comprising two sides and a spare. When it's stopped, my `mdadm --detail /dev/md*` returns `Raid Level: raid0` too. Working on that...

Comment: MilenTodorov, what happens if you `mdadm --run /dev/md0`? Assuming you get no serious errors, what does that do for the commands you've already run and pasted into your question?

Comment: @roaima Right, I could reproduce it. And actually I could reproduce the output shown in the Q by creating a RAID1 array out of one device and one spare (`mdadm -C -f /dev/mdN -l 1 -n 1 -x 1 /dev/... /dev/...`). I don't know how to make sense of it, though.

Comment: @fra-san that's what's worrying me ... that it was set up as live+spare, and it's the live that's failed

Comment: `mdadm --examine /dev/sd*`? also `dmesg` of assembly process if it exists

Comment: the raid0 shown for inactive arrays is a known bug but it's just misinformation in the output, doesn't mean a thing

Comment: Now I'm on work and later will try @roaima command and will give a feedback. I just didn't tried anything because I have a lot important files there and don't want to broke something that's why I asked here.

Comment: So I was able to boot with the failed HDD and software removed it from the RAID and now I'm have access to my other HDD and the RAID is still active but my question is if my HDD ever failed and won't turn on at all is it possible to access my other HDD from the RAID to recover my info ? Thank you all for the help I appreciate it !

Comment: If that's  your question please put it in the question text!

Comment: The question you added with your last edit isn't completely clear to me. I'd suggest using names consistently (e.g. `sda` and `sdb`) for the two HDDs - instead of "failed" and "other". Independently of that, a piece of advice about "important files": RAID is not backup. The two serve different purposes. RAID mainly aims at reducing downtime. Backup aims at recovering a previous version of data (outdated to some extent, depending on the frequency of backups).